# Unity Shader graph vertex displacement not working on mesh created at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to get a low poly water shader working with shader graph.
I am facing a strange issue, I can get my shader working on a plane, but it won't on a quad or a plane generated at runtime.

[Here is a picture of what both geometry look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJCXb.jpg)

[And here is my shader graph code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc0L6.jpg)

Finally, here is the code I use to generate mesh at runtime :

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        MeshFilter mf = GetComponent< MeshFilter > ();
        var mesh = new Mesh();
        mf.mesh = mesh;

        float width = 10;
        float height = 10;

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[4];

        vertices[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        vertices[1] = new Vector3(width, 0, 0);
        vertices[2] = new Vector3(0, 0, height);
        vertices[3] = new Vector3(width, 0, height);

        mesh.vertices = vertices;

        int[] tri = new int[6];

        tri[0] = 0;
        tri[1] = 2;
        tri[2] = 1;

        tri[3] = 2;
        tri[4] = 3;
        tri[5] = 1;

        mesh.triangles = tri;

        Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[4];

        normals[0] = -Vector3.forward;
        normals[1] = -Vector3.forward;
        normals[2] = -Vector3.forward;
        normals[3] = -Vector3.forward;

        mesh.normals = normals;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any advice :)

[EDIT]

[Here is the result with a quad from unity (it works)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxHgp.png)

Comment: "VERTEX displacement" is your clue here. How many verticies do you have and what can you expect from them? :-)

Comment: Actually, my plane is 10x10 square (of 2 triangles), so I have 121 vertices. But the thing is that it works for this plane, but not the quad generated by the code above :/

Comment: How could it possibly work for the code you show? It has only four verticies that can be displaced!

Comment: yeah, actually the code generates a quad (2 triangles and 4 vertices). But still, it works with a regular quad from unity.

Comment: That would be impossible. Once you add more verticies it will work.

Comment: It is possible with such geometry from unity assets (see EDIT in post). So it must be possible with a quad created from code.

Comment: A Plane primitive in Unity has about 200 vertices, so a vertex displacement shader can be applied to it. Your code generates a quad with only 4 vertices, so there are no vertices to displace. Btw, a Quad primitive is equal to your procedural quad, and I’m quite sure the results would be equally bad. Watch out, a quad and a plane primitives are different.

Answer (score 0):

It looks your normal vector is wrong because of you are creating plane mesh on xz-plane but normal is forward? it should be up or down I guess?

Comment: You are right, i just changed the normals. But I still have weird movements. Here is a video showing the difference between quad from unity editor, and the quad from code. [link](https://streamable.com/a3dxj)
Thanks for your time

Comment: I feel like the node "Position" in my shader is the one causing the issue. It seems it cannot find the vertex positions but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I found out !
It appears that I had to had **uvs** to the mesh. I don't really understand how it is linked to vertex position but why not.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. For investigation I placed a standad 3D object in the scene with the same shader and the shader worked as expected. The mesh filter showed the UVs as the only difference to my script created mesh. After adding UVs everything worked fine.